# How to select every date before now in timestamp?

Tags: datetime, forms

my database feild type is timestamp here is my code I used it but It also gave me today date 
I need every date before today

```
"SELECT * FROM {mytable} WHERE  date <".$now_timestamp."  "
```

please help me
Thank you

Comment: here is $now_timestamp variable

Comment: $now = new DateTime('now'); 
  $now_timestamp =$now->getTimestamp();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get yesterday's date instead of using a `DateTime` object:

```
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM {mytable} WHERE date < :timestamp';

$result = db_query($sql, array(':timestamp' => $yesterday));
```

Answer (score -1):

Timestamp is basically how many seconds have passed since 1st Jan 1970 UTC. To get the exact timestamp of Yesterday at 23:59 hour 59th second I can think of the following approach:

```
$yesterday = strtotime(((string) date('d-m-Y', strtotime('-1 day', time()))) . ' 23:59:59');
```

It's not really elegant, but if you really need exact time, then the above code should do the trick.

A breakdown of what's happening is:

```
$now = time();
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day', $now);
$yesterday_date = date('d-m-Y', $yesterday);
$yesterday_date_string = (string) $yesterday_date . ' 23:59:59';
$yesterday_timestamp = strtotime($yesterday_date_string);
```

Comment: Feedback on downvote?